# How to plot distance travelled on graph by agent(s) in Anylogic in Discrete Event Simulation?

Tags: anylogic, event-simulation, processmodel

Dear Anylogic Experts,

I am trying to calculate the cost based on distance travelled by the agents in GIS environment. Does anyone know how can I calculate this? The final graph function is supposed to look like this: Distance moved by Agent in km or meter multiplied by the Cost per km or meter.

The idea is to see which route will cost how much. The way I have moved agents in via PML. please see picture attached of the process taking place. [image: PLease see picture link here]

Answer (score 1):

there is no default way for this, several options:

1. Turn on "Model execution logging" and you will get total travelled distance for each agent.
2. In your `MoveTo` blocks, log the departure and arrival location (lat/lon) of your agent and use `getDistanceGIS(...)` to log the total distance from your agent

Comment: Hmmm. Seems like the fear was right. Since my distance vary on the network, I believe way 1 will be the only way :) 

Thank you Mr. Benjamin, appreciate your help.

Comment: no probs, @JahanzebAhsan. Please flag the reply as "useful" (small up-arrow next to it) so others can find the solution faster in the future. Good practice on StackOverflow :)